# How to replace JRDesignBand in a JasperDesign?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to update my JasperReports version from 4.0.1 to the current 5.5.0.

My reports are generated, therefore I use a template-report. I have to replace the DetailBand, so I'm using `getDetail()` to get the band of my template-detail-section. After extracting some information and creating a new `JRDesignBand newBand` I'm using `setDetail(newBand)`. Works!

With 5.5.0 this two methods are not available anymore. To get the band I can use something like this:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/542111/jasper-reports-317-450-changes-jasperdesigngetdetail

But how to replace `setDetail(newBand)`???
I found this peace of code:

```
((JRDesignSection)jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
```

But this adds the band, so I have 2 bands in my details-section. But I just need the new one...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `removeBand(band)` on the `JRDesignSection` to remove the old band. It shouldn't matter whether you do this before or after adding the new band, but it will 
leave you with just the new band present. E.g:

```
((JRDesignSection)jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(newBand);
((JRDesignSection)jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).removeBand(oldBand);
```