# Simple JasperReport Query

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Does *JasperReports* provide some functions in *Java* which I can use and change my jrxml.

Like change the font, add new detail section, add static text, delete something, add charts etc.

I want to do them like

```
someObject.setFont("Arial");
```

and this will set the object's font to Arial and I can also see the respective change in jrxml.

I know that *iReport* does this easily without any function call, but I want this thing with *Java* functions only as I am building some app.

If yes please provide a simple example or sites, links anthing from which I can learn. *JasperReports API* doc is not so good.

Comment: So you essentially want to manipulate the JRXML file programatically? You can do that by parsing the JRXML file (it is XML after all) using your favorite XML DOM-parser, manipulate the DOM object representation, and write the JRXML again

Comment: @mkl, yes I can do that surely, but isn't that cumbersome and error-prone. Thats why I need a API so when a client says hey I want to change font color on the webpage I will send request to the server where I will use java functions and just say changeFont(...) and it will take care of the rest. I hope I am clear now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JasperReports has an API that allows you to do this. The cornerstone of this is the [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) class, which represents your report in-memory. You should check out the [No XML Design Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html), which uses the API extensively to build a report from scratch only using java. Once I had seen that example, I found that by exploring the javadoc from the [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) class, I could quite easily find any method I needed to change elements on a report.

As an example, a basic approach for changing the font on an element would be to first load your JRXML into a JasperDesign object, find the element by its key, then call `setFontName`:

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("path/to/your/JRXML.file");
JRElement element;
for (JRBand band : design.getDetailSection().getBands()) {
    element band.getElementByKey("elementName");
}
if (element != null) {
    ((JRDesignTextElement) element).setFontName("Arial");
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269898/how-to-replace-jrdesignband-in-a-jasperdesign) for how to add a new band. The method of doing so changed in recent versions, so a lot of the examples and tutorials online are out of date.

When you are done modifying/creating your report, you can save it or compile it like so:

```
JasperCompileManager.writeReportToXmlFile(design, "path/to/your/output.jrxml");
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(design, "path/to/your/output.jasper");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GenericJon :) I was looking for the same. If you can please add some links from which I can study it would be awesome!!.

Also is there any error checking like what if client gave wrong dimension of band. Can it throw some exception from which I can identify where the fault is, if not I will have to check manually

Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I don't have any links to tutorials; I mostly worked out what I needed to do by trial-and-error and the javadoc. When you compile a report it will throw a JRException if the design is invalid, but it might not be easy to equate the error message with the inputs in your application. You'll probably want to do your own validation and feedback in your own code at the point where the design changes are made.

Comment: @GenericJon Hi, how to find the elements' key? Thanks.

Comment: @coastline You set the key yourself in the JRXML. `key` is an attribute of the `reportElement` tag that is inside every element.